# Is it possible to omit knockoutjs data-bind attribute in html output?

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I have item template for data binding via knockoutjs

```
<script id="ItemTeamplte" type="text/html">
    <div>some value: <span data-bind="text: someObj.someProp"></span></div>
</script>
```

and output is

```
<div>some value: <span data-bind="text: someObj.someProp">614</span></div>
```

How to omit

> data-bind="text: someObj.someProp"

attribute in the html output?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to remove the attributes, but why do you want to do this at all? What is problems with having the attributes there? And in the meanwhile you can check out Knockout.Punches http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/

Comment: Knockout operates at runtime against your rendered HTML. If remove the code it's looking for in the rendered output, it's not going to work.

Comment: @nemesv the reason is not to disclose data model sctructure

Comment: @Pete ok, I got it. I was thinking that binding attributes are required only during initial binding and then knockout could 'cache' that binding information for future updates.

Comment: Even if  you manage to remove the bindings on the client side, they still rendered with the initial server request into the DOM. Therefore it is meaningless. Besides actual Data Model can be inferred from a simple application that renders html on the server just as good as from data-binding attributes.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/AdamPflug/Knockout.Programmatic can help

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by extending the binding provider. Here's a quick example:

```
ko.bindingProvider.instance.getBindingsString = (function (originalFunc) {
    return function (node, bindingContext) {
        if (node.__savedBinding) {
            return node.__savedBinding;
        }
        var binding = originalFunc.call(this, node, bindingContext);
        if (binding && node.nodeType == 1) {
            node.__savedBinding = binding;
            node.removeAttribute('data-bind');
        }
        return binding;
    }
})(ko.bindingProvider.instance.getBindingsString);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/C5QHx/

Comment: Can I ask, where did you get that from? Or you managed to do it yourself? Just wondering how did you come to find that solution and how reliable it is.

Comment: Great answer! It should be noted though that *with this you're monkey patching Knockout itself*, not utilizing an actual Knockout-feature to do this.

Comment: @Alvaro Michael is [the #2 contributor](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/graphs/contributors) to the knockout repository, I think it's fair to say he probably wrote it himself, and it's probably fairly reliable (at least with the current version of knockout) :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks for clarifying it :) I had no idea.

Comment: Custom binding providers are a [supported feature in Knockout](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-2-custom-binding.html). However, the `getBindingsString` function is *internal* and only applies to the standard binding provider.

Comment: Tried it out with the `classBindingProvider` - so, good point re. this just working with the default `bindingProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, there is no *feature* in KO to do this. The attribute is there so Knockout can do its job.

You *might* have some luck by going through [the source code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout), and modify (or monkey patch) it to serve your purpose, though I also think that *might* be a pain to get right.

Comment: It seems it is possible!

Comment: Hmm, @MichaelBest's answer is to some degree equivalent to mine, except that he actually *shows* how to modify the source code (by monkey patching it). I would still claim that if you need to resort to monkey patching it can be considered "impossible" by regular usage of the library.