# Knockout.js too verbose?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm quite new to Knockout and I'm getting a bit surprised of the way it displays things in the resultilng DOM.

I'm adding a 4 `data` attributes in a row and one class, and I found out things start becoming to verbose when inspecting the resulting HTML markup to debug.

If I want to accomplish something like this:

```
<tr class="admin" data-user-id="10" data-user-email:'demo@demo.com' data-active="true">Alvaro</tr>
```

Ends up being too times longer in the resulting HTML markup:

```
<tr data-bind="text: name, css: type, attr:{ 'data-user-id': user_id, 'data-user-email': email, 'data-active': $root.isActive()}" class="admin" data-user-id="10" data-user-email='demo@demo.com' data-active="true">Alvaro</tr>
```

It makes inspecting the DOM a bit more difficult as many *hidden* data (or logic) is being displayed on the resulting markup.

Is this normal in these kind of frameworks ? (ember.js, angular.js...) or it is something just something particular from knockout.js?

Is there any way to prevent this kind of "duplicating" ?

Comment: You always have the option of creating a custom binding to hide away some of the config.

Comment: well its pretty common in SPA i.e angular etc . After rendering it tends to show bindings + rendered content as well which makes bit verbose .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Jeff Mercado's comment, if you created a custom binding that looked like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myCustomBinding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $data = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        element.setAttribute('data-user-id', $data.user_id);
        element.setAttribute('data-user-email', $data.email);
        element.setAttribute('data-active', ko.unwrap(bindingContext.$parent.isActive));
    }
}
```

You could apply it to your element like this:

```
<tr data-bind="myCustomBinding: $data"></tr>
```

And the resulting HTML when you inspect the DOM would appear like this:

```
<tr data-bind="myCustomBinding: $data" data-user-id="10" data-user-email="demo@demo.com" data-active="true"></tr>
```

Less chatty and now you have a reusable binding.

Also, you don't have to pass `$data` into your custom binding as I did in the example above. Instead, you could reference `bindingContext.$data` within the custom binding `init` function rather than unwrapping the `valueAccessor`. If you do that then you can pass anything over to your custom binding including an empty string since the `valueAccessor` will not be used in your custom binding. This would shorten up your HTML even more since it would start off looking like this instead: `<tr data-bind="myCustomBinding: ''"></tr>`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, could you provide an example of the case in which you don't pass the `$data` variable?

Comment: In `myCustomBinding` instead of unwrapping the `valueAccessor()` just use the `$data` property on the `bindingContext` e.g. `bindingContext.$data.user_id`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about the `data-bind` attribute persisting in the HTML after binding, you can remove that attribute using a custom binding provider. Here's one I wrote to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23620576/1287183

Comment: Interesting solution! Does it have any delay at all between the render and the removal of the `data-bind` attributes? Or it does it before it is rendered.